# How do you unlock Eye and Teeth operations?

Tags: surgeon-simulator

How do you unlock Eye and Teeth operations?

Comment: "Become an eye/dental surgeon!" would probably be the appropriate response. As for in game, Sentry said it all, it's a whole new buy. Even though that's questionable business on the game creator's side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are part of the [Anniversary Edition](http://steamcommunity.com/app/233720/discussions/0/34094415778737321/) and you have [to buy it](http://store.steampowered.com/app/317960/) to be able to play those mission. (Steam version)